# Getting sum on specific rows that match with each other in SQL using sum() group by and joining

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

These are the tables that I am pulling data from:

```
insert into students values
('861103-2438', 'Adam', 'Johnson', 'M', '1990-10-01'),
('911212-1746', 'Eva', 'Smith', 'F', '1991-08-20'),
('950829-1848', 'Anna', 'Washington', 'F', '1993-09-26'),
('123456-0980', 'Eric', 'Alonzo', 'M', '1990-05-26'),
('908023-2456', 'Bo', 'Ek', 'M', '1992-03-15'),
('098735-3456', 'Danny', 'Goss', 'M', '1992-02-01'),
('124345-3430', 'Mike', 'White', 'M', '1995-06-10'),
('124568-1345', 'Emily', 'Young', 'F', '1995-04-28'),
('908409-0010', 'Cathy', 'Lee', 'F', '1993-10-06'),
('124587-9088', 'Ben', 'Woo', 'M', '1992-11-30'),
('120953-0909', 'Anna', 'Washington', 'F', '1990-10-09'),
('120449-1008', 'John', 'Goss', 'M', '1995-10-26');

insert into courses values
('CS056', 'Database Systems', 'G1', 5),
('CS010', 'C++', 'U1', 5),
('ENG111', 'English', 'U1', 5),
('FIN052', 'Finance', 'G1', 5),
('PHY210', 'Physics', 'U2', 5),
('CHE350', 'Chemistry', 'U3', 5),
('BIO001', 'Biology', 'U1', 3),
('CS052', 'Operating Systems', 'G1', 5);

insert into registration values
('861103-2438', 'CS056', 4),
('861103-2438', 'CS010', 4),
('861103-2438', 'PHY210', 3.5),
('911212-1746', 'ENG111', 2),
('950829-1848', 'CHE350', 3),
('950829-1848', 'BIO001', 2.5),
('123456-0980', 'CS052', 3.5),
('123456-0980 ', 'CS056', 4),
('908023-2456', 'PHY210', 3.0),
('908023-2456','CS056',1.0),
('908023-2456', 'CS010', 2.0),
('124345-3430', 'FIN052', 2.5),
('124345-3430', 'CHE350', 4),
('908409-0010', 'CS052', 2),
('124587-9088', 'BIO001', 4),
('124587-9088', 'CS052', 3.5);
```

I'm having trouble when I am trying to add all the credits that each student has taken.

Sorry if the explanation was bad.

I inputted this, but it gives just gives me all the credits added up.

```
select students.studentID, students.firstName, students.lastName, sum(courses.credits) 
from students, registration, courses 
where courses.courseCode = registration.courseCode 
group by studentID;
```

Comment: Refer to [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) you really should have kicked by now.

Comment: sorry, I'm still a student and learning right now. Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll be grouping by `studentId`, use that as the driving table and left join the registration to see what they've registered to attend. Then from that join, join to the courses to get the credits for each course. The use of the IFF function is simply to convert null to 0 for students who have not registered for any course.

```
select S.STUDENTID, iff(sum(C.CREDITS) is null, 0, sum(C.CREDITS)) as TOTAL_CREDITS
from students S 
    left join registration R on S.STUDENTID = R.STUDENTID
    left join courses C on C.COURSECODE = R.COURSECODE
group by S.STUDENTID
;
```

| STUDENTID | TOTAL_CREDITS |
| --- | --- |
| 861103-2438 | 15 |
| 123456-0980 | 5 |
| 908023-2456 | 15 |
| 124345-3430 | 10 |
| 124568-1345 | 0 |
| 911212-1746 | 5 |
| 950829-1848 | 8 |
| 908409-0010 | 5 |
| 124587-9088 | 8 |
| 120449-1008 | 0 |
| 120953-0909 | 0 |
| 098735-3456 | 0 |